# DateTimePicker, obter primeiro e último dia do mês

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datetime, datepicker

Como faço para pegar o primeiro e o último dia do mês anterior, para preencher um `DateTimePicker` em tela?

Ex:

```
Data Inicial 01/07/2015
Data Final   31/07/2015
```

Comment: Poste o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Você quer fazer algo especificamente no controle `DateTimePicker` ou só quer ter esta informação em uma data qualquer? Coloque o que fez, explique melhor onde você quer chegar, qual o resultado deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta não está muito clara mas deve ser algo assim:

```
var data = picker.Value; //pega a data que está no controle
var mesAnterior = data.AddMonths(-1);
var primeiroDia = new DateTime(mesAnterior.Year, mesAnterior.Month, 1); 
var ultimoDia =  new DateTime(mesAnterior.Year, mesAnterior.Month,
        DateTime.DaysInMonth(mesAnterior.Year, mesAnterior.Month));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/unUuhW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dfmeAZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/FirstAndLastDayOfMonth.cs).

Tem inúmeras outras fórmulas de fazer isto. Cada uma pode ter uma vantagem em relação a outra mas em geral fará pouca ou nenhuma nenhuma diferença em coisas simples. Fiz um teste abaixo usando métodos de extensão, assim pode usar como se fosse parte do tipo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Funcionou perfeitamente .

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma resposta [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/41b298f3-421a-4159-86d1-2d68755f84e6/funo-que-recebe-uma-data-e-retorna-ltimo-dia-do-ms-anterior?forum=vscsharppt/%22aqui%22)

Vê se isso te ajuda também:

```
DateTime dtUltimoDiaMes = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Lembre-se disso. O último dia do mês anterior é o `primeiro_dia_mês_corrente menos_um_dia(AddDays(-1))`. Essa é a fórmula.

Comment: "Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para pegar o primeiro dia e o ultimo dia do **mês anterior** ?"

Comment: Só estava a apontar que o código calcula o ultimo dia do mês currente, enquanto que a pergunta pede o ultimo dia do mês anterior. Um pequeno (mas importante) detalhe.

Comment: @dcastro, entendi, mas se você ver o código que eu postei, ele pega um determinado mês e volta um dia, o que vai ser o último dia do mês anterior. Acho que é isso que ele pediu, pelo que eu li.